# How to implement S-Box in qiskit?

Tags: algorithm, qiskit, grover

I know that classically S-Box is just substitution like,

```
aes_sbox = [
    [int('63', 16), int('7c', 16), int('77', 16), int('7b', 16), int('f2', 16), int('6b', 16), int('6f', 16), int('c5', 16), int(
        '30', 16), int('01', 16), int('67', 16), int('2b', 16), int('fe', 16), int('d7', 16), int('ab', 16), int('76', 16)],
    [int('ca', 16), int('82', 16), int('c9', 16), int('7d', 16), int('fa', 16), int('59', 16), int('47', 16), int('f0', 16), int(
        'ad', 16), int('d4', 16), int('a2', 16), int('af', 16), int('9c', 16), int('a4', 16), int('72', 16), int('c0', 16)],
    [int('b7', 16), int('fd', 16), int('93', 16), int('26', 16), int('36', 16), int('3f', 16), int('f7', 16), int('cc', 16), int(
        '34', 16), int('a5', 16), int('e5', 16), int('f1', 16), int('71', 16), int('d8', 16), int('31', 16), int('15', 16)],
    [int('04', 16), int('c7', 16), int('23', 16), int('c3', 16), int('18', 16), int('96', 16), int('05', 16), int('9a', 16), int(
        '07', 16), int('12', 16), int('80', 16), int('e2', 16), int('eb', 16), int('27', 16), int('b2', 16), int('75', 16)],
    [int('09', 16), int('83', 16), int('2c', 16), int('1a', 16), int('1b', 16), int('6e', 16), int('5a', 16), int('a0', 16), int(
        '52', 16), int('3b', 16), int('d6', 16), int('b3', 16), int('29', 16), int('e3', 16), int('2f', 16), int('84', 16)],
    [int('53', 16), int('d1', 16), int('00', 16), int('ed', 16), int('20', 16), int('fc', 16), int('b1', 16), int('5b', 16), int(
        '6a', 16), int('cb', 16), int('be', 16), int('39', 16), int('4a', 16), int('4c', 16), int('58', 16), int('cf', 16)],
    [int('d0', 16), int('ef', 16), int('aa', 16), int('fb', 16), int('43', 16), int('4d', 16), int('33', 16), int('85', 16), int(
        '45', 16), int('f9', 16), int('02', 16), int('7f', 16), int('50', 16), int('3c', 16), int('9f', 16), int('a8', 16)],
    [int('51', 16), int('a3', 16), int('40', 16), int('8f', 16), int('92', 16), int('9d', 16), int('38', 16), int('f5', 16), int(
        'bc', 16), int('b6', 16), int('da', 16), int('21', 16), int('10', 16), int('ff', 16), int('f3', 16), int('d2', 16)],
    [int('cd', 16), int('0c', 16), int('13', 16), int('ec', 16), int('5f', 16), int('97', 16), int('44', 16), int('17', 16), int(
        'c4', 16), int('a7', 16), int('7e', 16), int('3d', 16), int('64', 16), int('5d', 16), int('19', 16), int('73', 16)],
    [int('60', 16), int('81', 16), int('4f', 16), int('dc', 16), int('22', 16), int('2a', 16), int('90', 16), int('88', 16), int(
        '46', 16), int('ee', 16), int('b8', 16), int('14', 16), int('de', 16), int('5e', 16), int('0b', 16), int('db', 16)],
    [int('e0', 16), int('32', 16), int('3a', 16), int('0a', 16), int('49', 16), int('06', 16), int('24', 16), int('5c', 16), int(
        'c2', 16), int('d3', 16), int('ac', 16), int('62', 16), int('91', 16), int('95', 16), int('e4', 16), int('79', 16)],
    [int('e7', 16), int('c8', 16), int('37', 16), int('6d', 16), int('8d', 16), int('d5', 16), int('4e', 16), int('a9', 16), int(
        '6c', 16), int('56', 16), int('f4', 16), int('ea', 16), int('65', 16), int('7a', 16), int('ae', 16), int('08', 16)],
    [int('ba', 16), int('78', 16), int('25', 16), int('2e', 16), int('1c', 16), int('a6', 16), int('b4', 16), int('c6', 16), int(
        'e8', 16), int('dd', 16), int('74', 16), int('1f', 16), int('4b', 16), int('bd', 16), int('8b', 16), int('8a', 16)],
    [int('70', 16), int('3e', 16), int('b5', 16), int('66', 16), int('48', 16), int('03', 16), int('f6', 16), int('0e', 16), int(
        '61', 16), int('35', 16), int('57', 16), int('b9', 16), int('86', 16), int('c1', 16), int('1d', 16), int('9e', 16)],
    [int('e1', 16), int('f8', 16), int('98', 16), int('11', 16), int('69', 16), int('d9', 16), int('8e', 16), int('94', 16), int(
        '9b', 16), int('1e', 16), int('87', 16), int('e9', 16), int('ce', 16), int('55', 16), int('28', 16), int('df', 16)],
    [int('8c', 16), int('a1', 16), int('89', 16), int('0d', 16), int('bf', 16), int('e6', 16), int('42', 16), int('68', 16), int(
        '41', 16), int('99', 16), int('2d', 16), int('0f', 16), int('b0', 16), int('54', 16), int('bb', 16), int('16', 16)]
]
def lookup(byte):
    x = byte >> 4
    y = byte & 15
    return aes_sbox[x][y]
```

How can i do the same in qiskit? There are many implementations but none has given me the correct output. As, i have copied circuit parts from many papers. I want to know how they decide where and what gates should be placed?

I have tried to implement GIFT and PRESENT S-BOX circuit given in "Efficient implementation of GIFT and PRESENT on quantum computers". The output did not match the expected result.